# java.lang.NumberFormatException type casting in kotlin

Tags: android, text, casting, kotlin

I want to do body mass index and it's pretty simple. but I could not do that. I get an error in type conversions, but I did not fix the problem. Hatam

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.

I guess the

```
result = (kiloText.toString (). ToInt ()) / ((boy.toString (). ToInt () 
boy.tostring (). toınt ())). todoubl a ()
```

this code has type conversion error how can i do this?

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var kilo:SeekBar
lateinit var boy: EditText
lateinit var hesapla:Button
lateinit var ideal: TextView
lateinit var kiloText: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    kilo=findViewById(R.id.seekbar)
    boy=findViewById(R.id.edt_boy)
    hesapla=findViewById(R.id.hesapla)
    ideal=findViewById(R.id.ideal)
    kiloText=findViewById(R.id.kilo)

    kilo.max=150
    kilo.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
            kiloText.text=p1.toString()
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar) {
            kiloText.text= p0.progress.toString()
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar) {
            kiloText.text=p0.progress.toString()
        }

    })

    hesapla.setOnClickListener({
        var sonuc:Double
        sonuc=(kiloText.toString().toInt())/((boy.toString().toInt())*(boy.toString().toInt())).toDouble()
      ideal.text=sonuc.toString()


    })

}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.

So we need to know the reason .

1.Use `kiloText.toString()` and `boy.toString()` will cause `NumberFormatException`

2.If `kiloText.text` and `boy.toString()`  are null, it will cause `NumberFormatException`

You can try this way .

**Change**

```
sonuc=(kiloText.toString().toInt())/((boy.toString().toInt())*(boy.toString().toInt())).toDouble()
ideal.text=sonuc.toString()
```

**to**

```
sonuc=(kiloText.text.toString().toInt())/((boy.text.toString().toInt())*(boy.text.toString().toInt())).toDouble()
ideal.text=sonuc.toString()
```

**Edit**

[source](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html)

```
/**
* Parses the string as an [Int] number and returns the result.
* @throws NumberFormatException if the string is not a valid representationof a number.
*/
@kotlin.jvm.JvmVersion
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun String.toInt(): Int = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(this)
```

Comment: Would it not be better to validate the fields separately so that you don't end up with "some string isn't a number so the calculation can't happen" error?

Comment: Yes, it will be better.@PaulHicks

Comment: For safer side i have add like this `textView_countdown.text?.toString()`. In my case how can I use `.toInt()` ? @KeLiuyue

Comment: Try to use like this .`textView_countdown.text?.toString()?.toInt()` .And you should check the `textView_countdown.text?.toString()` whether it was null .@esu

Comment: And you can check `NumberFormatException - if the string is not a valid representation of a number.` .[https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html)